# numpy most efficient way to get row index of true values by columns

Tags: python, numpy

I want to get row index of true values by column from a 2-D ndarray. By far, I have a solution with a for loop. But I think this isn't efficient because there exits a python native for-loop. I try to figure out a vectorized solution but failed.

**Update**: It's not necessary to be a vectorized solution, more efficient is better.

```
arr = np.random.randint(2, size=15).reshape((3,5)).astype(bool)
print arr

[[ True False  True False  True]
 [False  True False  True  True]
 [ True  True False False  True]]

def calc(matrix):
    result = []
    for i in range(matrix.shape[1]):
        result.append(np.argwhere(matrix[:, i]).flatten().tolist())
    return result

print calc(arr)
[[0, 2], [1, 2], [0], [1], [0, 1, 2]]
```

Note: I want row indices grouped by columns. And when a column is all False, I need to get an empty list `[]` instead of skipping.

Comment: That looks a lot like the `scipy.sparse` `lil` format.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Approach #1**

Here's one vectorized NumPy approach to have those row indices grouped in a list of arrays -

```
r,c = np.where(arr.T)
out = np.split(c, np.flatnonzero(r[1:] != r[:-1])+1)
```

Sample run -

```
In [63]: arr = np.random.randint(2, size=15).reshape((3,5)).astype(bool)

In [64]: arr
Out[64]: 
array([[False, False,  True,  True, False],
       [ True,  True, False, False,  True],
       [ True,  True, False, False,  True]], dtype=bool)

In [65]: r,c = np.where(arr.T)

In [66]: np.split(c, np.flatnonzero(r[1:] != r[:-1])+1)
Out[66]: [array([1, 2]), array([1, 2]), array([0]), array([0]), array([1, 2])]

In [67]: calc(arr)
Out[67]: [[1, 2], [1, 2], [0], [0], [1, 2]]
```

**Approach #2**

Alternatively, we could use `loop comprehension` to avoid that splitting -

```
idx = np.concatenate(([0], np.flatnonzero(r[1:] != r[:-1])+1, [r.size] ))
out = [c[idx[i]:idx[i+1]] for i in range(len(idx)-1)]
```

We are using `r,c` from approach #1.

**Approach #3 ( To output empty lists/arrays for all 0s cols )**

To account for all zeros columns, for which we need empty lists/arrays, here's a modified approach -

```
idx = np.concatenate(([0], arr.sum(0).cumsum() ))
out = [c[idx[i]:idx[i+1]] for i in range(len(idx)-1)]
```

We are using `c` from approach #1.

Sample run -

```
In [177]: arr
Out[177]: 
array([[ True, False, False, False, False],
       [ True, False, False, False,  True],
       [ True, False,  True, False,  True]], dtype=bool)

In [178]: idx = np.concatenate(([0], arr.sum(0).cumsum() ))
     ...: out = [c[idx[i]:idx[i+1]] for i in range(len(idx)-1)]
     ...: 

In [179]: out
Out[179]: 
[array([0, 1, 2]),
 array([], dtype=int64),
 array([2]),
 array([], dtype=int64),
 array([1, 2])]
```

**Approach #4**

Here's another way to handle all `0s` cols -

```
unq, IDs = np.unique(r, return_index=1)
idx = np.concatenate(( IDs, [r.size] ))
out = [[]]*arr.shape[1]
for i,item in enumerate(unq):
    out[item] = c[idx[i]:idx[i+1]]
```

We are using `r,c` from approach #1.

Comment: And your solution is a little flawed, when a column is all `False`, I need get empty list `[]`.

Comment: Avoiding that splitting make your solution really fast!

Comment: Thank you very much! Approach #3 is exactly what I want. By the way, your intelligence is unbelievable! I also answer questions tagged with `numpy` and `pandas` and see many your great answers. I really wonder how you learn these two libraries.

Comment: I would change `r,c = np.where(arr.T)` to `c, r = np.where(arr)`. It isn't guaranteed that transpose gives a view. So in some cases the second variant could be significant faster.

Comment: @DerWeh The overhead cost with that one is the later need for a sorting `c` based on `r`, as I am slicing based off `c's` that I am using in sequence for slicing.

Comment: @gzc Well I started off with MATLAB. Then, NumPy was an easy extension off it and then pandas deals with NumPy at some level, so got onto that too, all through trying to answer questions on here :)

Answer (score 0):

My solution would be

```
column, row = np.where(arr.T)
unique, indices = np.unique(column, return_index=True)
res = np.split(row, indices[1:])
```

As pointed out, we are still missing the columns which are false,
these can be inserted using the information of unique:

```
missing = np.setdiff1d(np.arange(arr.shape[-1]), unique)
for mm in missing:
    res.insert(mm, np.array([], dtype=int))
```

It is a bit slower than what @Divakar proposed. However, I find it more readable, as the complicated `np.flatnonzero(r[1:] != r[:-1])+1` part can be avoided, so it is immediately clear what happens.

Comment: Please check my note. Approach #1 and #2 by Divakar is flawed. So is yours.